# Calendar Ant Design: How to show events with variable dates?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am looking for a way to show events in an Ant Desing Calendar using dateCellRender with the dates from an variable object, like this one:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "content": "Example",
        "date": "01/05/2022",
        "horario": [
            "2022-05-26T06:00:00.925Z",
            "2022-05-26T07:00:00.478Z"
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "content": "Example",
        "date": "08/05/2022",
        "horario": [
            "2022-05-26T11:00:00.859Z",
            "2022-05-26T14:00:00.976Z"
        ],
    }
]
```

The normal way to show events is using a switch, like you can see in this CodeSandbox from AntD: https://codesandbox.io/s/ruj266

My object comes from the backend and will always change, there is a way to show dynamic events using that object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `antd` calendar works with `moment` object, so when you try to render the calendar, you can covert the value of current date to string by using `format` method of moment object like this:

```
<Calendar dateCellRender={(value) => {
  const stringValue = value.format("DD/MM/yyyy");
  return (...);
};} />;
```

and compare the result of `format` method with date values in your data, I implemented an example by using of your data example here on codesandbox:

[antd-calendar-example](https://codesandbox.io/s/notice-calendar-antd-4-20-6-forked-e93bui?file=/demo.js)

is this what you are looking for?